# "else if" Conditions in Javascript Calculator

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, calculator

I'm trying to adapt a calculator that was made by someone else who used to work at my company. Unfortunately I can't get hold of him at all and was wondering if someone here could help me. My javascript knowledge is limited so please bear with me if this sounds a stupid question or if I'm missing something obvious. I can't find any info on this elsewhere, so any help would be much appreciated!

Here is the current code for the section I want to change:

```
function date(){ 
        var the_date  = new Date();
    enter code herevar the_year  = the_date.getFullYear();
    ret_age=Number(document.calculator.year.value);
    gender=Number(document.calculator.sex.value);
    a=the_year-ret_age;
    if (a<=36)
      {
    document.calculator.number3.value=68;
      }
    else if (a>36 && a<=45)
      {
    document.calculator.number3.value=67;
      }
      else if (a>=45 && a<=60)
      {
    document.calculator.number3.value=66;
      }
        else if (a>60 && gender==1)
      {
    document.calculator.number3.value=65;
      }
        else if (a>60 && gender==0)
      {
    document.calculator.number3.value=65;
      }

    else
      {
      alert("Our calculator is having trouble working out your state 
pension age. You have been given a default age of 68. Feel free to 
change it.");
        document.calculator.number3.value=68;
      }

        }
```

I want to add in these new 'else if' options, but I think that there is a problem with the number of conditions in each.

```
        else if (a>60 && gender==0)
      {
    document.calculator.number3.value=65;
      }
        else if (a>60 && <=62 && gender==0)
      {
    document.calculator.number3.value=62;
      }
        else if (a>63 && gender==0)
      {
    document.calculator.number3.value=60;
      }
```

Am I doing something wrong with trying to use eg. `a<61 && <=63` alongside the gender condition? This appears to only work when I say one condition for the number, eg. `a<60`

Is there any way to use these two conditions in the else if, or will I have to do something different?

It would be great if someone could help - again, apologies if this question is poorly explained. If you need any more info to help then please let me know! I'm not sure what I'm doing. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

You missed an 'a' after '&&' on this condition: `else if (a>60 && <=62 && gender==0)`

Comment: Thanks for your help! All working great now. I knew it would be something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The && indicates that another condition most be true in order for the if statement to validate to true. It does not apply a condition statement to the previous variable.

For example if you had two if statements as follows:

```
if(x > 1){
   if(y < 1){
      // do something
   };
};
```

They could be combined into a singly if statement like this:

```
if(x > 1 && y < 1){
    // do something
};
```

Essentially both sides of the && (or || for an "or" condition) need to be able to evaluate outside of the other statements.

So in your case as previously stated in another answer, you need to changes your if statement from:

```
else if (a>60 && <=62 && gender==0)
      {
    document.calculator.number3.value=62;
      }
```

To:

```
else if (a>60 && a<=62 && gender==0)
      {
    document.calculator.number3.value=62;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

your coditions inside the if statements are wrong

replace `else if (a>60 && <=62 && gender==0)` with `else if (a>60 && a<=62 && gender==0)`